# Can I do it by not using topological group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

Let $M(n;R)$ denote the set of all $n×n$ matrices with real entries (identiﬁed with $R^{n^2}$ and endowed with its usual topology) and let $GL(n;R)$ denote the group of invertible matrices. Let G be a subgroup of $GL(n;R)$. Deﬁne   $H$ = { $A \in G$ : there exists a continuous function $f$ from $[0,1]$ to $G$ and $f(0) = A$ and $f(1) = I$.}

Then $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Can I do it by not using topological group?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in your last sentence?

Comment: Read the question carefully. I want an answer which is different from the answer u cited..Please don't try to block the question.

Comment: I did read carefully, but I don't understand what you mean by "Can I do it by not using topology group?". And I didn't know that you had seen that other question. By the way, there is another question linked to the one I mentioned above, did you also see that one?

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is path-connected component of $G$ which contains the identity matrix. To show this is a normal subgroup, you need to show closure under multiplication, inversion, and conjugation. I'll get you started with closure under multiplication.

Given $A,B\in H$, we need to show $AB\in H$, which requires finding a path from $AB$ to $I$. Let $f_A$ be a path from $A$ to $I$, and $f_B$ from $B$ to $I$. Then let 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}A\cdot f_B(2x) & 0\le x\le 1/2\\f_A(2x-1)& 1/2\le x\le 1\end{cases}
$$
You can then show that $f$ is a continuous function $[0,1]\to G$ for which $f(0)=AB$ and $f(1)=I$.

Comment: I think for proving inverse I have to take $B = A^-2$ and for normality I have to just multiply $A$ and $A^-1$ from left and right respectively with any continuous function f(x) .